empty interior and openness
In my teacher's lecture notes have these two notes
• Every proper subspace of a topological linear space has empty interior.
• Every proper subspace of a topological linear space is not open.
My question: is every set with empty interior is not open?.

Ask yourself: What's the interior of an open set?

@LeeMosher, open set is equal to its interior.

Well then now you can answer your own question.

The empty set has empty interior, yet it is open. But that's the only example. A subspace can't be empty anyway.

@LeeMosher, so every nonempty proper subset with empty interior is not open?

@user3879021 Well, yes, because for a nonempty proper subset, being open would mean being equal to its interior. As you say that the subset is nonempty, but its interior is empty, they cannot be equal. Hence, such a subset cannot be open.

The following statement is true in any topological space (not just topological vector spaces):

Every non-empty set with empty interior is not open.

The proof is simple. Let $X$ be a space with at least one element and $A \subseteq X$ be open. Either $A = \emptyset$, or $A$ is non-empty. Suppose that $A$ is non-empty and $a \in A$. Since essentially by definition ${\rm Int} A = A$ when $A$ is open, then $a \in {\rm Int} A$; i.e., the interior of $A$ is non-empty.
